# How to set proper font size Libgdx

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I am creating my fonts at runtime using the FreeTypeFont extension. I saw here a way to match the font to the screen resolution:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/77658/how-to-match-font-size-with-screen-resolution?rq=1

However, the problem is the following: on my laptop, which has a low PPI the font is too small, while on my phone which has a high PPI the font is too big.

My code:

```
public BitmapFont createFont(FreeTypeFontGenerator ftfg, float dp) {
        FreeTypeFontParameter f = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
        f.size = (int)(dp * Gdx.graphics.getDensity());
        f.color = Color.BLACK;
        f.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest;
        f.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest;
        //ftfg.scaleForPixelHeight((int)(dp * Gdx.graphics.getDensity()));
        return ftfg.generateFont(f);
    }
```

And then I have:

```
font = createFont(new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf")), 12);
font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

There seems to be a solution here:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79487/problem-to-match-font-size-to-the-screen-resolution-in-libgdx
But I don't quite get it.

What is the proper way to create fonts, or set the fonts sizes in order for them to have the same proportions compared to the screen (be it on desktop or android) and not look distorted on resizes?

Comment: you can try this f.size = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*.001f;

Comment: I have to do it like this `f.size = (int) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * .001f);`. But then i get an error: `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No cap character found in font`.

Comment: If you want the same look of application on different screens you should use `Viewports`. `FitViewport` is possibly what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tried using viewports and they don't seem to have the effect I want. Some just stretch everything (`StretchViewport`) and it looks distorted, while others don't fit on my screen. `FitViewport` doesn't seem to have any effect on the font.